# How to create a database in Oracle using JDBC?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I want to create a new database on an Oracle server via JDBC. I cannot seem to connect to the database without providing an SID: using a URL like `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//[IP]:1521` results in an error of  "`ORA-12504, TNS:listener was not given the SID in CONNECT_DATA`"

Alternatively, if I log into a specific SID, I can run most DDL commands except for `CREATE DATABASE foo` which fails with an error of "`ORA-01100: database already mounted`"

How am I supposed to create a database if I cannot connect to the server without specifying a specific database and cannot create a database if I am already logged into a specific database?

Comment: Are you really sure that you want to create a database?  What other RDBMS products call a "database" is generally similar to what Oracle calls a "schema" (or, depending on context, a "tablespace").  There is generally only one database on a server, that database houses many different schemas which are collections of database objects.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK creating a database needs an internal and direct connection which can *only* be done by logging in directly on the server (normally a user account called 'oracle').

One reason for that: users are stored in the database itself. No database = no user to connect to by an external client.

Please also note Justin's comment about oracles database schemas. This is probably what you are looking for

Comment: Wrong. With [static service registration in `listener.ora`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10836/listenercfg.htm#NETAG297), and [`REMOTE_LOGIN_PASSWORDFILE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams210.htm#REFRN10184) initialization parameter value set to either `SHARED` or `EXCLUSIVE`, the remote connection to an idle instance is possible, provided that the password for the user with `SYSDBA` privilege exists in the password file.

Answer (score 0):

What you need are following commands:

CREATE TABLESPACE

CREATE USER

and few GRANT ... TO ... -- to have rights to connect and create objects, at least